# Separating the payment function from PayPal Checkout paypal.Button.render method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

PayPal `payment` method is not getting the updated price details which has to be passed as input parameter for creating payment.

The `paypal.Button.render()` method gets called initially with the input parameter - `price` which is `0.00`. But when the price gets updated on field change, it is not taking the updated `price` value, and calling the `payment` function with the old value - `0.00`.

```
function createPaypalPayment(price, recordId){
    angularLoad.loadScript('https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js')
    .then(function() {
        paypal.Button.render({
            env: 'sandbox', 
            payment: function(data, actions) {
                createPayment(price, recordId){
                    /*..some code goes here*/
                }
                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response)
                })
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Here the I'm using this in an AngularJS service.

How can I get the updated value of price here when I do a field change and call the `createPaypalPayment(price, recordId)` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Paypal's Server side integration for this. That way you can easily change/update the payment price. Follow this [Link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/server-integration/#1-set-up-your-client-to-call-your-server).